# Character conversion

Tags: keypress, keylistener, keyevent

Using Java/Netbeans.  I thought this would be simple but . . .

I have a JTextArea.  When I type an 'x' or 'X' I want to display 'θ'.  This was easy.

I want to add "CTL-x" to display lower 'x' and "CTL-SHIFT-X" to display upper 'X'.  This I cannot get to happen.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I cannot come up with code to accomplish this.  I am looking for suggestions.